# Properties of relation $R$ on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}:\;(a,b)R(c,d) \iff a -c = b -d$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Still doing relation properties exercises, I'm now trying what seems to be a somewhat different type: now the relation is over a cartesian product $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

I normally have no problems determining if it is reflexive or symmetric, but for the other ones that require more complex proofs I keep on hitting dead ends:

> Over $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$, $(a,b)R(c,d) \iff a -c = b -d$.
>   Determine the properties of the relation $R$.

**Reflexive**

Yes. We have to prove that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N} : (a,b)R(a,b)$

$$(a,b)R(a,b)$$

$$a - a = b - b$$

$$0 = 0$$

**Symmetric**

Yes. We have to prove that $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N} : (a,b)R(c,d) \implies (c,d)R(a,b)$:

$$(a,b)R(c,d)$$

$$a - c = b - d$$

$$-(a - c) = -(b - d)$$

$$c - a = d - b$$

$$(c,d)R(a,b)$$

**Antisymmetric**

We have to prove that $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N} : (a,b)R(c,d) \land (c,d)R(a,b) \implies (a,b) = (c,d)$:

$$(a,b)R(c,d) \land (c,d)R(a,b)$$

$$(a - c = b - d) \land (c - a = d - b)$$

$$(a - c = b - d) \land [-(c - a) = -(d - b)]$$

$$(a - c = b - d) \land (a - c = b - d)$$

$$(a - c = b - d)$$

If I can prove that $a = c$ and $b = d$ I would be done - however, it seems I've hit a wall here. Maybe that's a hint that it isn't antisymmetric?

**Transitive**

We have to prove that $\forall a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{N} : (a,b)R(c,d) \land (c,d)R(e,f) \implies (a,b)R(e,f)$:

$$(a,b)R(c,d) \land (c,d)R(e,f)$$

$$(a - c = b - d) \land (c - e = d - f)$$

$$a - d + f - e = b - c + e - f$$

I was hoping to end up with $a - e = b - f$, but I can't get rid of those $c$ and $d$ in the equation.

**Total**

We have to prove that $\forall a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : (a,b)R(c,d) \lor (c,d)R(a,b)$.

Let's suppose that $(a,b)\not R(c,d) \land (c,d)\not R(a,b)$.

$$(a,b)\not R(c,d) \land (c,d)\not R(a,b)$$

$$(a - c \not = b - d) \land (c - a \not = d - b)$$

$$(a - c \not = b - d) \land (a - c \not = b - d)$$

$$(a - c \not = b - d)$$

However, that is false, because clearly if you pass $(1,1)R(1,1)$, you would have $1 - 1 \not = 1 - 1$. Since this is a contradiction, our supposition is wrong, and therefore the relation is indeed total.

---

As you can observe, I require feedback for the antisymmetric and transitive proofs. Additionally the total proof is a bit fishy to me. What do you think?

Comment: As a strategy to approach the problem I would advice you to try to understand what does the relation mean. To say $a-c=b-d$ is equivalent to say that the segment with ends $a$ and $b$ has the same lenght of the segment with ends $c$ and $d$. So you can easily see that your relation is congruence of segments and then its properties are easy to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For antisymmetry: Perhaps you are "stuck" because you can't establish antisymmetry. What you can do is show, by providing a ***counterexample***, that antisymmetry ***fails:***

E.g. Note that we have $\;(5, 4)\, R\, (3, 2)\;\land \;(3, 2) \,R \,(5, 4),\;$ but $\,(5, 4) \neq (3,2).\;$

---

For transitivity, you have:

> We have to prove that $\forall a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{N} : (a,b)R(c,d) \land (c,d)R(e,f) \implies (a,b)R(e,f)$:
>
> $$(a,b)R(c,d) \land (c,d)R(e,f)$$
>
> $$(a - c = b - d) \land (c - e = d - f)$$

Now we just need a little algebra, by isolating $c-d$ in each of the two equations above, and equating them. That way we can rid ourselves of both $c$ and $d$.

We have $$(a - c = b - d \iff {\bf c - d = a - b})\; \land (c - e = d - f \iff {\bf c - d = e - f})$$

So $$\;a-b = e-f\; \iff \;a - e = b-f$$
Hence $(a, b) R (e, f)$, as desired.

---

For totality, consider the ordered pairs $(5, 4), \;(1, 4)$. Then $5 - 1 \neq 4 - 4$, and $1 - 5 \neq 4 - 4$. Hence we have a counterexample in which it is not the case that  $(5, 4) R (1, 4)$, nor is it the case that $(1, 4) R (5, 4)$.

Comment: The only reflexive, symmetric and antisymmetric relation is the identity. A total and symmetric relation is the trivial relation (every element is related to every element).